# Can IE8 post cross-domain requests from HTTP to HTTPS?

Tags: ajax, authentication, internet-explorer-8, xdr

I'm trying to make a secure authentication POST request from an HTTP domain to an HTTPS domain using Ajax.  For Firefox, Chrome and other modern browsers, it's possible to do this using a CORS request.  Unfortunately IE8 and IE9 don't support CORS, which makes this type of authentication difficult.

In point 7 of [XDomainRequest - Restrictions, Limitations and Workarounds](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ieinternals/archive/2010/05/13/xdomainrequest-restrictions-limitations-and-workarounds.aspx), Eric Law mentions a workaround for IE's limitation on HTTP-to-HTTPS cross-domain requests.  However, while [the workaround demo](http://www.webdbg.com/test/xdm/httptohttps.asp) works for IE9, it doesn't work for IE8.

Is there any other workaround for IE8 to send a cross-domain POST request from an HTTP domain to an HTTPS domain?

Note that sending a JSONP GET request probably won't due, because passing user credentials in the authentication request's URL parameters means that the credentials would be recorded in web server logs files.  If those logs were compromised, then users' credentials would be compromised too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The demo doesn't work because IE8 doesn't support the `addEventListener` method for adding event listeners. Instead, the demo should use the `attachEvent` method.

I have verified that it works in IE8 if the correct `attachEvent` method is used.