# Is it possible to make a cross domain javascript request to HTTP from HTTPS?

Tags: ssl, https, cross-domain

There are several questions that relate to this, but they're either very specific, inconclusive or outdated:

[Is it possible to make a cross domain request from https to http in IE?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20474653/is-it-possible-to-make-a-cross-domain-request-from-https-to-http-in-ie)

[Can IE8 post cross-domain requests from HTTP to HTTPS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9890841/can-ie8-post-cross-domain-requests-from-http-to-https)

[Cross domain HTTP requests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34879977/cross-domain-http-requests)

[Cross domain request from HTTP to HTTPS aborts immediately](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11690191/cross-domain-request-from-http-to-https-aborts-immediately)

And a few others.

As of now, is it at all possible to make any (GET, PUT, POST...) HTTP request, within JavaScript, to a server that does not have a valid SSL certificate, in a page served from a HTTPS server? Without, of course, asking the user to trust a self-signed cert or disable protections.

I've tried `fetch` and `XMLHttpRequest` requests, but they either get blocked by the browser because of CORS or generic "TypeError: NetworkError".

My specific predicament is that I have a home server accessible through a dynamic DNS provider (free tier). I cannot easily obtain an SSL certificate because my ISP blocks HTTP requests to port 80, which makes Let's Encrypt HTTP-01 challenge basically impossible.

Comment: HTTPS **requires** a (valid) cert. Don’t have a valid cert? Use an HTTP (which is _not_ HTTPS) endpoint and _hope it is not upgraded_ (eg. 3xx on the remote or upgrade-insecure header). The title and premise is very misleading because it appears the goal is to “make an HTTP request (without encryption/cert) to an HTTPS endpoint”, which is not possible.

Comment: @user2864740: I think he wants a cross-origin request like this: User goes to `https://example.com` and receives web page containing javascript. When the javascript runs it makes a request to `http://my-server.314159.dyndns.com/`.